# Chrome dev tools settings: where is the Experiments tab to Allow custom UI themes?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am using chrome version 36+

according to [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/devtools-theme-zero-dark/bomhdjeadceaggdgfoefmpeafkjhegbo) page, I should be able to allow custom themes using the following instructions:

> ### Installation Instructions
>
> - Add this theme
> - Goto chrome://flags and Enable Developer Tools experiments.
> - **Open developer tools settings, select Experiments tab, and check 'Allow custom UI themes'**.
> - Reload devtools.

I do not see such a tab in the dev tools settings. I see only 'general', 'workspace', and 'shortcuts'

Comment: Want to add my problem in case others had the same. After enabling on /flags I was manually restarting chrome. I guess you MUST select their button on the bottom of /flags page after enableing item. Touche' Google

Comment: same issue, I did relaunh chrtome

Answer (score 21):

These are some simple steps to follow, hope it will be helpful.

1. Open a new chrome tab, type `chrome://flags`
2. Find, **"Enable Developer Tools experiments."** using ctrl/cmd+f or simply searching for it by scrolling down the page.
3. Click the **"enable"** link
4. Click on **"Relaunch Now"** at the bottom of the page.
5. After restarting Chrome, open DevTools, DevTools settings, and select the experiments tab.

Now select the experiment you want (e.g. *"Allow custom UI themes"*).

You need to **reload devtools** after: `Alt-R` will reload devtools itself, or you can just close and reopen it.

Comment: You HAVE to use the "Relaunch Now" button. For me and some others anyway.

Answer (score 12):

To get to the Dev Tools Experiments area you have to click on the gear icon in the inspector.

[image]
[image]

If still not working you should go to:

chrome://extensions/

And click the 'Enable' checkbox for the DevTools extension you wish to enable.

Answer (score 11):

Had the same issue,

I found I was going to browser settings which is NOT where you should be going to , 
You need to go to developer setting .

[image]

i.e right click>inspect element> dev tools

Comment: this is the only answer that is accurate with the current version of chrome. Kind of confusing, though, the first picture should be deleted as it is going to throw people off.

Answer (score 4):

You need to restart the browser after changing the flag at chrome://flags

Answer (score 1):

I found it. There is a checkbox under experiments tab:
 Allow custom UI themes

Comment: I don't see it. Where is the experiments tab? I only see General, Workspace, Shortcuts. That must be the best-hidden thing in the world of UX

Answer (score 1):

Restart chrome just not means to close the chrome and then open it. you should click the 'Relaunch Now' button of the flags tab. and then it's work for me.

Answer (score 1):

2022 update: There doesn't seem to be any option in chrome://flags but there is an option:

`devtools > settings > experiments > Allow extensions to load custom stylesheets`

Answer (score 0):

loislo's answer is absolutely right (You need to restart the browser after changing the flag at chrome://flags). But notice that your chrome can work in the background. Go to the tray, look for the chrome icon and exit.

Answer (score 0):

1. Navigate to `chrome://flags/`
2. Find and enable Developer Tools experiments Mac, Windows, Linux, Chrome OS
3. Relaunch Chrome, open develop tool, setting, you will see experiments tab.

My Chrome version: Version 61.0.3163.100